# Thread safety with @Scheduled and @Async, Java

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

I took this code:

```
private Queue<Object> myQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

public enqueue(Object obj) {
  myQueue.add(obj);
}

@Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
public void publish() {
  final List objsToPublish = Lists.newArrayList();
  final int listSize = myQueue.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
     objsToPublish.add(myQueue.poll());
  }

  expensiveWriteOperation(objsToPublish);
}
```

However, it's a problem if publish() takes away control during some other operations running in this software, so I tried to make the expensive call asynchronous, like so:

```
private Queue<Object> myQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

public enqueue(Object obj) {
  myQueue.add(obj);
}

@Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
public void publish() {
  final List objsToPublish = Lists.newArrayList();
  final int listSize = myQueue.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
     objsToPublish.add(myQueue.poll());
  }

  work(objsToPublish);
}

@ASync
void work(List objsToPublish) {
  expensiveWriteOperation(objsToPublish);
}
```

I am concerned about two things.

1) Does this code work, even if enqueue is called at any time, even mid-work()?

2) Am I passing the data from the queue in the right way?

Comment: Your `@Async` doesn't do anything. It's called from the same class, so it'll be just a regular method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `work()` method must be public and must be called from outside the class that has the `publish()` method. If this is Spring, you are most likely using dynamic proxies in which case once you call `publish()` from elsewhere, the `@Async` annotation of the `work()` method is no longer at play since you are already *inside* the proxied instance.

Try this:

```
interface AsyncInternalWrapper {
    void work(List objsToPublish);
}


@Service
public class AsyncInternalWrapperImpl implements AsyncInternalWrapper {
    @Async
    public void work(List objsToPublish) {
      expensiveWriteOperation(objsToPublish);
    }
}
```

then

```
@Autowired
private AsyncInternalWrapper wrapper;

@Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
public void publish() {
  ....

  wrapper.work(objsToPublish);
}
```

On a side note, since this is a scheduled process, it does not require user interaction. So what is the real benefit of making the `publish()` call return quicker? You may want to think twice as of what benefit (if any) does this async operation provide and not over-engineer something without a good argument.

Regarding your concerns, bear in mind that the `publish()` will be executed in its own thread by the Executor service, so naturally you are already doing "async" call. I'm guessing this is the impetus for using the concurrent queue.  What happens with `@Async` is that you are spawning (or taking from the thread pool)  another thread in addition to the one executing `publish()`

Comment: Thanks for the info. My thought is that the publish() result as-is may take, say, 1 second. If the scheduler goes off in the middle of a call that we expect to return to an external service within 10ms, we'll fail to return on time. I am confused by the other thing you said --- are you suggesting that the the @scheduled method is ALREADY asyncronous and will not block other code that is running?

Comment: Yep, annotating with @Scheduled by definition also requires a task executor in your context which will be responsible for allocating threads from the pool for the execution of `publish()`. This is naturally async operation as it is executed outside of any other calls. 

See: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html